# Using Firestore as a Cache for SQL Aggregation

Tags: firebase, salesforce, google-cloud-firestore

I'm not sure if this is the place to ask this, but I have a best practices question.

I have a dashboarding service fed by Salesforce data that displays the number of Task X performed this week (X being Opportunities Closed - Won, Leads Created, etc).

Currently, the data is being pulled regularly and stored in a SQL database, which is mapped to a REST API that the Client App calls to get the aggregations between two date values, and will be fed additionally by Webhook calls via SF's Insert Triggers.

I want to know if having a Firestore Collection as a Cache for Aggregated SQL is a good idea, or if there is a better approach.  The benefits I see are reduced traffic on my SQL server, instant updates (if the "cache" (Firestore) is updated, the client's value updates instantly as well).

When data is pulled from SF or a new record is received via the Insert Trigger/Webhook, I can update the Firestore record and the client will receive the change immediately.

My idea for a Firestore Document would be

```
{
  user: "123",
  sfOwnerId: "124",
  sfTaskType: "Opportunities Closed Won This Week",
  count: 23
}
```

Is this a good idea?  Is there a better one out there?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy of storing the aggregated data is what the [Firestore documentation suggests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) for aggregation, so I think it's pretty solid idea.

An alternative strategy would be to only store the Salesforce data in Firestore as it comes in, not aggregated, and let the client perform the aggregation. This can be achieved by [subscribing to real-time updates to a query of Collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection). In this setup, you would perform the calculation within the `onSnapshot` callback (assuming you're using the Web environment).

The advantage here is a *possible* increase to performance, since Cloud Functions often suffer from "cold start" latency.

> Note: Several of the recommendations in this document center around
>   what is known as a cold start. Functions are stateless, and the
>   execution environment is often initialized from scratch, which is
>   called a cold start. Cold starts can take significant amounts of time
>   to complete. It is best practice to avoid unnecessary cold starts, and
>   to streamline the cold start process to whatever extent possible (for
>   example, by avoiding unnecessary dependencies).

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips)

Comment: Would that be super heavy?  I've looked into it, and my queries wouldn't be too insane - If the period is in between two dates, I can have the client fetch all after a specific date, and then splice it to not include the data after the `endDate`.

Comment: That depends on how complex your aggregation calculations are. Your date range filter strategy sounds good to me.

Comment: I just thought of this: You can cut down your initial results even further by querying for docs with a "start date" greater than or equal to your date range's "start date" AND less than or equal to your range's "end date" (with two `where` calls). This should cut down on the number of docs you have to exclude whose "end date" go past your date range's "end date" .

Comment: I'll do that!  thank you for your input!